# trying to undertstand lexical scope in example

Tags: javascript

```
var carlike = function(obj, loc){
    obj.loc = loc;
    obj.move = move;
    return obj;
};

var move = function(){
    this.loc++;
};

var ben = carlike({}, 9);
```

In the example above how is it that `obj.move` in the `carlike` function has access to the `move` function even though it is declared after the `carlike` function is declared. In other words when I call `ben.move();` at the end why does it not return `undefined`?

Citing from a known book:

> No matter where a function is invoked from, or even how it is invoked,
>   its lexical scope is only defined by where the function is declared

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting

Comment: See [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting).

Comment: @haim770 but these are function expressions and not declarations. so they do not get hoisted.

Comment: @Yapartase, Even though the `move` variable is declared after the `carlike` function, it's still accessible because the *declaration* is hoisted. As for the value of the variable, it's also getting initialized before `carlike` is invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a scope issue. The code in the function doesn't have to reference `move` until it's actually called. That happens *after* `move` has been initialized, so it works.

The code inside `carlike` does contain a reference to `move`, and yes at the point that function is constructed the value of `move` isn't set. That doesn't matter, however; when the function is called later, the value of `move` will be set.  If you moved the initialization of `ben` to *before* the initialization of `move`, then the code would not work.

Answer (score 1):

Well, due to hoisting your code will be equal to:

```
var carlike, move, ben;

carlike = function(obj, loc){
    obj.loc = loc;
    obj.move = move;
    return obj;
};

move = function(){
    this.loc++;
};

ben = carlike({}, 9);
```

and now `carlike` has access to `move` due to closure.

[This](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html) may be worth reading, it shows a very peculiar example in the beginning.

Comment: closure is throwing me off a bit. It was my understanding that closure ensures that a function has access to its outer variable environment even after their containing function has popped of the execution stack. However I don't see how this is the case here?

Comment: @Yapartase yeap, I'm not totally sure that this case is also called "closure" but, well, you can put it this way: if the variable is not declared in the function, interpreter looks for such variable declaration in the outer scope and does so until it reaches the global scope or finds a declaration and uses the corresponding value.